# How make Google Chrome Developer Console show up by pressing F12 in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, safari

In the OS X version of Google Chrome the Developer Console uses this stupid key combination of Alt+Cmd+I instead of F12, which is the de-facto standard key used in pretty much any other browser:

- Firefox Mac uses F12
- Chrome Windows uses F12
- Internet Explorer uses F12
- Opera also uses F12

So, how can I remap it only for Chrome? (Firefox Mac already uses F12)

BTW, which is the key for Safari? The documentation at Apple's website says it's also Alt+Cmd+I but it doesn't work for me:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/KeyboardShortcuts/KeyboardShortcuts.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcut and select App Shortcuts in the left panel. Add a new shortcut clicking on plus symbol and fill it like the image below.

[image]

You may have to use <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> if you have unselected the option `Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys' on Keyboard tab.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I have my F keys as regular function keys, not multimedia keys. I'm using Yosemite (10.10)

Comment: If you type the menu title exactly as menu title that can see on Google Chrome menu must work. A typo, prevent it to work.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Since my OS is not in English, I had to type it exactly in my language as it was written in the menu. Thanks!